# Bandwith usage of google cloud insatnces

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

how to get the bandwidth usage of instances hosted in google cloud instances?
I have 10 instances running in my google cloud account. i need to take the bandwidth usage for all servers.
8 instances are centos 7 and 2 are windows server 2012 R2.

Comment: Did you enable webserver logging? Export your logfiles into any number of products to generate bandwidth and traffic reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackdriver monitoring service offers a simple interface for surfacing and alerting on the GCE metrics.
You can monitor the bytes received and sent with this metric under GCE VM instances: sent bytes and received bytes. I believe this should give you a picture of the bandwidth.
The link will guide you in the steps to create the [chart](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/)

VPC Flow log is another tool on GCP. VPC Flow Logs record a sample of network flows sent from and received by VM instances. These logs can be used for network monitoring, forensics, real-time security analysis, and expense optimization.
You can get more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-flow-logs)

Comment: I do not recommend VPC Flow Logs for web server bandwidth monitoring. The cost is $0.50 per GB.